# php checking div style block or none

Tags: php

I am trying to check my div style also with my code here

```
<?php
    $Vidvid="Ab9kbmIAyLE";
    if(isset($_GET["Vidvid"]))
    {
        $Vidvid=$_GET["Vidvid"];
    }
?>
```

I don't know much in php , I think `if(isset($_GET["Vidvid"]` means id or name that gets in url like `page.php?id=Vidvid` am i right in this ?

If it's right, then I want to make it to check a div style also.
like if link is `page.php?id=Vidvid` and if div style is block

What i mean is to add something on if like checking div style also

## 2 Code

```
<?php 
$feed = "hello";
if(isset($_GET["feed"])) {
    $feed = $_GET["feed"];
    echo 'yes';
} else {
    echo 'no';  
}
?>
```

Comment: `$_GET['Vidvid']` means this `page.php?Vidvid=something`

Comment: PHP has very little to do with style rules inside html markup...

Comment: @Mazz thx for your comment, i am trying to add 2 things on if. 1 if in url was `something` but it's already there also i want to do "And if div style is block or none"

Comment: @Mazz i have updated my question and added #2 code, can you please tell me what am i doing wrong there

Comment: If you want to set the get value in your php code, you should do `$_GET['feed'] = "Hello"`

Comment: @Mazz Except in this case the `Hello` would fail because it’s in the wrong case.

Comment: your answer is different than @Manngo is answer bro. ceck his answer below. i am asking about getting some like page.php?id=something

Comment: @wes I’m not clear what you mean with “checking div style”. In your logic in part 2, if you send `?feed=hello` you will certainly get __yes__, otherwise __no__.

Comment: @Manngo what i meant in my second code if my link was like this page.php?id=hello then it must show "yes" on the page

Comment: that worked i got yes now, what i meant about style is, now my code is checking the link if it was hello then it will show yes. also i want the code to check div style like, if div is display block or none. what i mean is how do i check for 2 things on if isset @Manngo

Comment: @wes I’ll edit my answer, but you’re still confusing things here. If `id` is before the `=`, then _that_ is the index in the `$_GET` array.

Comment: @Manngo i am sorry because i am a little terrible on explaining things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’ve got it the wrong way round.

```
//  page.php?Vidvid=…
    $Vidvid="Ab9kbmIAyLE";
    if(isset($_GET["Vidvid"])) {
        $Vidvid=$_GET["Vidvid"];
    }
```

Data sent on the query string is stored in the `$_GET` array. The *name=value* pairs are translated to `$_GET[name]=value` in the array. In your code example, you’re looking for `?Vidvid=…`.

If you’re really sending `?id=`, you should be checking for `$_GET['id']`.

```
//  page.php?id=…

    if(isset($_GET['id'])) {        //  does id=?
        $value=$_GET[id];       //  get value
    }
```

Comment: as i have it like this `$Vidvid="Ab9kbmIAyLE";` then url will be like this `page.php?Vidvid=Ab9kbmIAyLE` am i right ?

Comment: i have updated my question and added #2 code, can you please tell me what am i doing wrong there

Comment: @wes In answer to your first comment, yes.

Comment: thank you i understand now the if isset thing. i learned something. but i was wondering how do i make it like this `if(isset($_GET["id"])) AND IF DIV STYLE IS BLOCK OR NONE` { echo 'yes'; }